# Getting a random GPS coordinate with a country parameter?

Tags: google-geocoding-api

Is it possible to pass the country name to the Google geocoding API and tell it to return a random GPS coordinate within the country?

Answer (score 3):

No. You can geocode a country and will get a fixed latlng inside that country, some sort of "center".

You could try adding a few random 4-5 digit numbers to get a random postal code, but there is a risk that it may geocode to a street address in a different country:

https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#q%3D62343%2520canada

You could try adding jittering within the `viewport` or `bounds` but may end up in the ocean or in another country, look at the red and blue rectangles here for "usa":

https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#q%3Dusa